# Match nearest timestamp without set_index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that contain event activities from various applications.

I want to merge them together and match up the events from the 2nd dataframe where the date field is less than(before) the date in the 1st dataframe wherever the user and system are the same.  Also, if there is no event in Data2 or the only events in Data2 occur on or after the dates in Data1, those should just return as null, NaN, or blank.

I've found numerous ways to do this by using set_index and nearest, however if I set the index to the 3 columns in question I get errors since my index would contain duplicate values in the index.  The error about the index needing to be unique makes perfect sense, however now I am wondering how I can do this without relying on indexes.

Sample data:

```
data1 = {
'user':["bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "jeb", "sue"], 
'system':["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"], 
'date':[
    '2022-12-11 10:00:00', 
    '2022-12-11 10:00:00',
    '2022-12-11 10:00:01', 
    '2022-12-09 10:00:01', 
    '2022-12-10 11:00:01', 
    '2022-12-15 11:00:01',
    '2022-12-10 10:00:01',
    '2022-12-10 10:00:01'],
'other_data': ["Blah", "Blah","Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah"]
}  

data2 = {
'user':["bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "jeb", "sue", "sue", "ted"], 
'system':["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A"], 
'date':[
    '2022-12-11 11:00:00', 
    '2022-12-11 10:00:00',
    '2022-12-11 09:59:00', 
    '2022-12-11 11:00:00', 
    '2022-12-11 10:00:00', 
    '2022-12-11 09:59:00', 
    '2022-12-10 08:00:01', 
    '2022-12-01 10:00:01', 
    '2022-12-13 10:00:01', 
    '2022-12-01 10:00:01'],
'other_data': ["Blah", "Blah","Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah"]
}  

dfData1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
dfData1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfData1['date'])
dfData2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
dfData2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfData2['date'])
```

Looking to get a dataframe returned similar to this:

| user_1 | system_1 | date_1 | other_data_1 | user_2 | system_2 | date_2 | other_data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bob | A | 2022-12-11 10:00:00 | Blah | bob A | 2022-12-11 09:59:00 | Blah |  |
| bob | A | 2022-12-11 10:00:00 | Blah | bob A | 2022-12-11 09:59:00 | Blah |  |
| bob | A | 2022-12-11 10:00:01 | Blah | bob A | 2022-12-11 10:00:00 | Blah |  |
| bob | A | 2022-12-09 10:00:01 | Blah | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| bob | B | 2022-12-10 11:00:01 | Blah | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| bob | B | 2022-12-15 11:00:01 | Blah | bob B | 2022-12-11 11:00:00 | Blah |  |
| jeb | A | 2022-12-10 10:00:01 | Blah | jeb B | 2022-12-10 08:00:01 | Blah |  |
| sue | B | 2022-12-10 10:00:01 | Blah | sue B | 2022-12-01 10:00:01 | Blah |  |

How does one merge data like this on multiple columns without setting those columns as the index to avoid the issue of duplicate index values?

Edit:

This gets me closer by adding temp date fields to merge and using pd.merge_asof

```
dfData1['mdate'] = dfData1['date']
dfData2['mdate'] = dfData2['date']
dfData1.sort_values(['mdate'], inplace=True)
dfData2.sort_values(['mdate'], inplace=True)

pd.merge_asof(
    dfData1[(dfData1['user']=="bob") & (dfData1['system']=="A")], 
    dfData2[(dfData2['user']=="bob") & (dfData2['system']=="A")], 
    on="mdate", 
    by=["user", "system"], 
    suffixes=["_1","_2"]
)
```

This also does a less than or equal to on the compare and there doesn't appear to be a just less than merge option, but I can also just add 1 second to all the all values in  dfData2["mdate"] to compensate for that.

However, the merge only works if I am subsetting to unique user/system rows for the merge_asof.  I could loop through each subset of user/system data in the dataframes and reassemble later, but I'm still wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You probably want to look at using `merge_asof`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: That's pretty close.  I had to copy the date field into a temp field in each dataframe for the merge(I want both date fields in the output), but after that the merge only works if I subset the merge down to each user/system  and run a merge_asof on each user/sytem combination.  I could loop through those combos and reassemble the finished dataframe, but I'm curious if there's a way to do it without looping through the data like that

Comment: I've added more details to the original question

Comment: you can pass `allow_exact_matches=False` to turn the <= behavior into <. Including by=['user','system'] means it will match only when those values are identical, so you shouldn't need to subset and loop separately. Is that still not working? what issues are you running into?